# Increase memory size of Apache Tomcat Windows Service for a Java application created by an executable file

Tags: java, apache, jvm, executable, tomcat6

We have a legacy Java web application which we deploy to a Windows Server 2012 machine using an executable file and need to increase its memory pool size, since we get a lot of Out of memory exceptions.

It creates its own folders on Program Files including tomcat bin folder and a Windows service named "Apache Tomcat servicename" which is basically Tomcat version 6 but when I try to edit its Java options through tomcat6w.exe it says that this service is not installed on the system.

Is there a way to change the tomcat service being used by the application to a tomcat service installed from http://tomcat.apache.org/

Or maybe edit the service.bat (or any other file?) when creating the executable to hardcode the memory pool size there?

There is a line in service.bat like below:

```
"%EXECUTABLE%" //US//%SERVICE_NAME% ++JvmOptions "-Djava.io.tmpdir=%CATALINA_BASE%\temp;-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager;-Djava.util.logging.config.file=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties" --JvmMs 128 --JvmMx 256
```

Comment: You need to check what happens in an executable that creates a service and make changes there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to edit the Tomcat RAM usage through Registry by running `regedit`, browsing to:

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Wow6432Node > ApacheSoftwareFoundation >
   Procrun 2.0 > apache-tomcat > Parameters > Java
```

and editing following values:

```
JvmMs  REG_DWORD   0x00000800 (2048)
JvmMx  REG_DWORD   0x00001000 (4096)
```

The above applies when Tomcat is installed as a Windows Service and through a custom executable file and there is no access to its configuration through the `tomcatxw.exe` manager.

Answer (score 3):

Your Tomcat will have two exe files, Tomcat6.exe and Tomcat6w.exe

Suppose your service name is 'MyService' as shown in 'Windows Services', now rename Tomcat6w.exe as MyServicew.exe (notice that there is a 'w' also in the file name).

Now double click this MyServicew.exe, and a intuitive UI is presented for you to Monkey around with the service arguments.

All the best!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you did not installed Tomcat with JSS installer. You could use tomcat6w if you have installed Tomcat using JSS Installer.

At this point, you need to follow these steps:

- Run the shortcut located under Start Menu > All Programs > Apache Tomcat x > Configure Tomcat
- Under the Java tab, make any adjustments for memory pool.
- Save changes by clicking Apply.
- Restart Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Increase these parameters in service.bat file
`--JvmMs 128 --JvmMx 256` to `--JvmMs 1024 --JvmMx 2048`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1. Go to windows registry and find directory
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\htfty\Parameters\Java
2. You can see the parameters JvmMs and JvmMx over there. Change them to desired values and restart service.

Comment: @Alex Never mind I see you already have the solution. I had drafted the answer yesterday but forgot to post it.

Answer (score 0):

There sould be a file named `catalina.bat` ( `setenv.bat` in apache tomcat 7+ ) in the bin directory of tomcat installation. You can add your options to CATALINA_OPS and after restarting tomcat they should be applied. For checking if there applied use jvisualvm (it shows you what options are set for your jvm) .

Comment: This doesn't apply when Tomcat is running as a Windows Service.

Comment: just a typo,  they should be catalina.bat and setenv.bat, I've updated my post

Comment: I meant that setenv.bat is not getting called when Tomcat runs as a Windows service. "All the environment variables described here and the "setenv" script are
used only if you use the standard scripts to launch Tomcat. For example, if
you have installed Tomcat as a service on Windows, the service wrapper
launches Java directly and does not use the script files." More info here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RUNNING.txt